# Tomcat 6.0 doesn't start

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to start Tomcat 6.0, it pops-up a command window but immediately closes. Cant catch what's written in that popped up window.

So I put some PAUSE on catalina.bat, and see that it got to the end of the batch file, where it does:

```
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" 
-Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" 
-Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" 
-Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" 
-Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
```

Where right after it executed the line above, it pops up a very quick prompt window and closes

any suggestion on where to start looking?
I already copied out the whole bin folder from another person's that has working Tomcat, so all the batch file are the same - but mine still not work.

Comment: Have you ran the catalina.bat from the cmd window, instead of just double clicking the bat file?

Comment: This turn out to be something really stupid on my part. I had an instance of tomcat console still open from previous tries that's just sit there suspended. Amidst all the windows I had opened while trying to debug this problem, that left over console is the reason Tomcat wont work. Once I closed it, and re-start, it's all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting my answer from my comment as an answer so it's easier for everyone else to see:

This turn out to be something really stupid on my part. I had an instance of tomcat console still open from previous tries that's just sit there suspended. Amidst all the windows I had opened while trying to debug this problem, that left over console is the reason Tomcat wont work. Once I closed it, and re-start, it's all good

Answer (score 0):

I would first check that the `conf/server.xml` is configured properly, more importantly that the connector ports are trying to start on available ports.

I believe you can see which ports are being used on Windows with: `netstat -an |find /i "listening"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problem due to a dll file called msvcr71.dll .. You can find this file in your default jre6/bin directory. Copy this file and paste it in your Windows/system32 directory. If it asks you for a "replace this file" then the issue might be something else. If it copies successfully then i m sure the problem is solved. Tomcat should start then. Try it out.